# Solidity event listener

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, events

This web3js event listener is part of a Voting Dapp. The listener listens for a transactions and re-renders the page to show updates.

```
listenForEvents: function() {
App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {

  instance.votedEvent({}, {
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'

  }).watch(function(error, event) {
    console.log("event triggered", event)
    // Reload when a new vote is recorded
    App.render();
  });
});
},
```

Even after a lot of searches,i cannot find an explanation for the part

```
{
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}
```

I think this part is causing to render the app in loop.
Event declaration is like

```
event votedEvent (uint indexed _candidateId);
```

The statement that calls the event is

```
votedEvent(_candidateId);
```

Any links or topics to search for will be helpfull.Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Removing** App.render(); solved for me. 
Because we render the app while **initialising** the solidity class.